# If function returning values as NAs

Tags: r

I'm doing a basic analysis of how many values are missing, suppressed etc. in a large dataset. I'm using the function below to categorize the various types of missing data.

```
Iffunction2 <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "NA",ifelse(x == "-1", "Suppressed", ifelse(is.null(x), "Blank", ifelse(x == "Not Provided", "Not Provided", "Value"))))
```

Oddly, for one column (d138 below), what appear to be actual values are being returned as NA (as in the grey italicized NA) by this function. The data in this column is of type "double". I've also tried converting to "integer" but no luck.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Best,
Rachel

---

EXTRACT

```
    structure(list(d101_eligible_training_provider = c("Quincy College", 
"LARE INSTITUTE", "Springfield Technical Community College", 
"Network Technology Academy Institute", "Network Technology Academy Institute", 
"John Mason Institute at Hellenic University"), d103_provider_address = c("1250 Hancock Street Quincy MA  02169", 
"6 Campanelli Drive Andover MA  01810", "1 ARMORY SQUARE SPRINGFIELD MA  01105", 
"100 Pleasant Street Malden MA  02148", "100 Pleasant Street Malden MA  02148", 
"436 Amherst Street Nashua NH  03063"), d104_entity_type = c("Other", 
"Private For-Profit", "Higher Ed: Associate's Degree", "Other", 
"Other", "Other"), d105_program_name = c("Certificate in Digital Marketing", 
"MEDICAL BILLING/MEDICAL SECRETARIAL(W/0 GED PREP)", "Online Spanish Medical Interpreting Certification Program", 
"Coding And Web Development 2 Program", "Certified Professional Ethical Hacker", 
"Desktop Application User / Introduction"), d106_program_description = c("Digital marketing helps organizations promote and sell products and services through online marketing methods such as social media messaging website ads Facebook marketing campaigns Google Adwords and more. It's vital to develop a marketing strategy that keeps up with the technology.", 
"THIS PROGRAM IS DESIGNED TO RESPOND TO THE NEEDS O F THE MEDICAL RELATED ENVIRONMENT.", 
"Online Course. English/Spanish.  This course will help prepare new and experienced interpreters to work in hospitals health clinics law offices governmental agencies and more.  This program is open to all languages but students must be able to fully comprehend and communicate in both English and Spanish. Prospective students will be screened for pronunciation accuracy comprehension and overall readiness for the course. Must be 18 years or older.", 
"This course covers some important technologies of modern Server-Side development.", 
"Certified Information Systems Security Office training and certification program prepares and certifies individuals to analyze an organization's information security threats and risks and design a security program to mitigate these risks.", 
"Core program includes several desktop application tools typically used in everyday business. This program can be customized with electives depending on the student's employment requirements and personal goals. The core program includes Word Processing Spreadsheets E-mailand Presentation Tools with electives such as general database operation accounting software office communication tool reporting and project management tools."
), d107_program_url = c("http://www.quincycollege.edu", NA, "http://www.stcc.edu/wdc", 
"http://www.ntai.net", "http://ntai.net", "http://www.JohnMasonInstitute.com"
), d108_program = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), d109_associated_credential = c("None Provided", 
"None Provided", "None Provided", "None Provided", "None Provided", 
"None Provided"), d110_cip_code = c(52.1402, 52.0402, 16.0103, 
11.0201, 52.1206, 52.0402), d111_non_wioa_tuition_cost = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), d112_non_wioa_supplies_cost = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), d113_program_length_hours = c(330, 
440, 60, 240, 400, 272), d114_program_length_weeks = c(11, 22, 
10, 12, 20, 8), d115_program_prerequisites = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), d116_program_format = c("This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only.", 
"This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only.", 
"This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only.", 
"This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only.", 
"This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only.", 
"This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only."
), d117_program_soc_occupation_1 = c("13-116100", "43-601100", 
"27-309100", "15-113100", "11-302100", "43-601400"), d118_program_soc_occupation_2 = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), d119_program_soc_occupation_3 = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), d120_total_served = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1), d121_total_exited = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d122_total_completed = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d123_total_employed_q2 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1), d124_total_employed_q4 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), 
    d125_median_earnings = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d126_total_credential = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d133_total_wioa_served = c(-1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1), d134_total_wioa_exiters = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1), d135_total_wioa_served_with_ita = c(-1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1), d136_total_wioa_exited_with_ita = c(-1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1), d137_total_wioa_completed = c(-1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1), d138_cost_per_wioa_num = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), d139_total_wioa_exiters_employed_q2 = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d140_total_wioa_exiters_employed_q4 = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), d142_total_wioa_credential = c(-1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1), c_wioa_completed_percent = c(-1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1), c_total_employed_WIOA_q2_percent = c(-1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1), c_total_employed_WIOA_q4_percent = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), c_completed_percent = c(-1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1), c_total_emp_q2_perc_comp = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1), c_wioa_earned_cred_percent = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
    -1), c_cost_per_wioa = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), c_q2_employment_percent = c(-1, 
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), address = c("1250 Hancock Street Quincy", 
    "6 Campanelli Drive Andover", "1 Armory Square Springfield", 
    "100 Pleasant Street Malden", "100 Pleasant Street Malden", 
    "436 Amherst Street Nashua"), city = c("Quincy", "Andover", 
    "Springfield", "Malden", "Malden", "Nashua"), state = c("MA", 
    "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "NH"), zip = c(2169, 1810, 1105, 
    2148, 2148, 3063), lat = c(42.26, 42.65, 42.1, 42.43, 42.43, 
    42.78), long = c(-71, -71.14, -72.58, -71.05, -71.05, -71.52
    ), cip_formatted_4 = c(52.14, 52.04, 16.01, 11.02, 52.12, 
    52.04), reportingstate = c("MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
    "MA"), CIP_Title = c("Marketing.", "Business Operations Support and Assistant Services.", 
    "Linguistic, Comparative, and Related Language Studies and Services.", 
    "Computer Programming.", "Management Information Systems and Services.", 
    "Business Operations Support and Assistant Services.")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data with `dput(head(data))`, so that we can have a clear idea of how your data set looks like.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR thanks! Extract using dput(head(data)) added to post above. Please also note that the offending column is d138!

Comment: First you don't have `null` value in your data set. So you can drop `is.null` to another logical expression. But I don't understand in what way you would like to change your data set. `d138_cost_per_wioa_num` is of type integer before any transformation.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, because I want to analyze what's missing, I'd like to use the "if" expression in my post above to recast everything as a type of missing data. For d138, I'd like to differentiate between blank/NA and actual values. But the actual values are showing up as "NA" when I apply the if function above. (And I realized the reason it's already showing as an integer is because I already tried converting from double to integer and didn't remove this line from my code before applying dput). Does that make sense?

Comment: I unfortunately don't get it, you specified in your code that if there was `NA` value it should return `"NA"` which is not actually `NA` values and that's what your function does.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the problem. In the test data you've entered, all values for df$d138_cost_per_wioa_num are missing already. Also, could you include how you're planning on applying your function - Iffunction2?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it this is an approach to characterizing what I'll call `constants` as seen from an `rle$lengths` point of view, where all values are the same, and `is.na` treated separately.

I would record and control my indices differently than your `ifelse` approach as it will provide opportunity to do things differently, be flexible should you discern the data as served has changed, and allow you to exclude from treatment items that are otherwise correct but at first appear `constant`, say reporting_state.

Assuming your data.frame/tbl is called constants_df, and using your `structure(` above, get index of all columns that have the same value for all entries (not NAs) on a transposed data.frame:

```
 constant_t <- t(constants_df)
 constant_data_t <- vector(mode = 'integer') # to receive rle$lengths
 for (j in 1:nrow(constant_t)) {
 constant_data_t[j] <- rle(constant_t[j, ])$lengths[1]
 }
 # index where all values are the same, in this case 6L
 constant_t_idx <- which(constant_data_t == 6L)
 > constant_t_idx
 [1]  7  8 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
[26] 39 40 41 42 50

 # what are the values? strip out tibble stuff 
 constant_t_vals <- unname(unlist(constants_df[1, constant_t_idx]))

 unique(constant_t_vals)
 [1] "1"                                                                               
 [2] "None Provided"                                                                   
 [3] "0"                                                                               
 [4] "This program provides online instruction, e-learning, or distance learning only."
 [5] "-"                                                                               
 [6] "-1"                                                                              
 [7] "MA" 

> which(constant_t_vals == "-1")
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

> which(is.na(constants_df[1, ]) == TRUE)
[1] 10 11 31
# are all column entries NA or NA constants `?NA`
> any(is.na(constants_df))
[1] TRUE
# does that really mean they're all NA
> is.na(constants_df[, c(10:11, 31)])
     d111_non_wioa_tuition_cost d112_non_wioa_supplies_cost
[1,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
[2,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
[3,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
[4,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
[5,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
[6,]                       TRUE                        TRUE
     d138_cost_per_wioa_num
[1,]                   TRUE
[2,]                   TRUE
[3,]                   TRUE
[4,]                   TRUE
[5,]                   TRUE
[6,]                   TRUE
# is so
```

You can take the concepts and make indices and apply your characterization, suppressed, not provided & etc. You may decide to treat columns that are NA differently from those that are merely '-1' and only replace '-1' with suppressed in those columns

```
>simple_minus_1 <-setdiff(which(constant_t_vals == "-1"),which(is.na(constants_df[1, ]) == TRUE))
>simple_minus_1
 [1]  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
> constants_df[, simple_minus_1] <- 'suppressed'
> constants_df[, 7]
[1] "suppressed" "suppressed" "suppressed" "suppressed" "suppressed"
[6] "suppressed"
```

On further consideration, you might decide not to change your sourced data, but to use the index approach to see how things evolve thru time, as this appears to be a through time reporting system you are assessing. What's reported on first sourcing may be different subsequently.